# Different MAPE results in forecast accuracy in R using same dataset and model

Tags: report, time-series, prediction

I am getting a shift in the decimal point of the MAPE in the accuracy output for a stlf forecast using the same dataset and model.  Basically the decimal point seems to have shifted from the initial forecast run a couple of weeks ago from a MAPE of 9.838669993 to 983.867 for a run a week later.  None of the other values in the accuracy or summary reports have changed.  What is causing this?  I have run the same script. I am a novice in R and would be very grateful for any tips that you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. The mape reported in v4.05 of the forecast package is 100 times too large. It will be fixed in v4.06, hopefully out soon.